# How to receive brocast with VOICEMAIL

Tags: android

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/VoicemailContract.html

i don't know how to make a brocast receiver with VOICEMAIL. When you receive a voicemail,you will see "NEW VOICEMAIL" in notification,the icon just like a tape.

here is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".VoiceBrocast" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_VOICEMAIL" />
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.voicemail.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL" />
```

i tried to register in xx.java,but it's no works.

MainActivity.java:

```
    protected VoiceBrocast mUiBroadcastReceiver;

       mUiBroadcastReceiver = new VoiceBrocast();
    IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.ACTION_NEW_VOICEMAIL");

 MainActivity.this.registerReceiver(mUiBroadcastReceiver, mIntentFilter);
```

VoiceBrocast.Java

public class VoiceBrocast extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("voicemail");
    }
```

}

when i received a voicemail, nothing to print, i can't see "voicemail" in LogCat.

Comment: how can you make sure you received a voicemail broadcast？From your code , it's just a very simple broadcast registration，and there is no reason that it does not work. Please Check where you have send the broadcast。

Comment: i'd use Log.d instead of System.out

Comment: i downloaded a demo in official website. and the demo can send a voicemail to yourself, after i sent a voicemail to myself, i can find the voicemail in my cellphone. maybe the demo was not sent a broadcast,so i want to ask how to receive a voicemail broadcast and send a broadcast.

Comment: let me know if you have found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that else is wrong, but one problem is: the intent action is not called `"android.intent.action.ACTION_NEW_VOICEMAIL"` but `"android.intent.action.NEW_VOICEMAIL"`.

Perhaps you mixed it up with the constant name on the VoicemailContract class which is `VoicemailContract.ACTION_NEW_VOICEMAIL`.

Comment: Thanks your answer .Do you konw how to obtain Voicemail information?

Comment: Someone sent a Voicemail to me , and i want to fetch the guy's number and content , how can i do? thx

Comment: I tried to fixed the intent action , android.intent.action.NEW_VOICEMAIL~~but the BroadcastReceiver don't work. i found many information about how to Broadcast VOICEMAIL,but no information can help.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no standard way to get the voicemail information. For example on my phone and service provider, the only indication I get is an SMS message from the provider, the phone itself doesn't seem to know about voicemails. This is the case both on my Android phone and my iPhone. So, no, there is no way for me to obtain any voicemail information.

Answer (score 0):

> The minimum permission needed to access this content provider is ADD_VOICEMAIL

Do you have such permission ?

Comment: com.android.voicemail.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL

Comment: yes~~i have writed the permission in AndroidManifest              <uses-permission android:name="com.android.voicemail.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL" />